# Prevent Jayway JsonPath from striping quotes from json string

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm currently experimenting with Jayway JsonPath and I'm having problems transforming a property name from a json string. For example I'm trying to rename de "id" property name to "id2" in the following json string :

{"id":"id","description":"Description"}

I'm using the following java statement to do this

```
String s2 = JsonPath.parse(s).renameKey("$","id", "id2").json().toString();
```

The problem with this is that this transformation strips the quotes from the json string :

{description:Description,id2:id}

Is there a way to prevent jsonpath to strip the quotes ?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `json().toString()`, try `jsonString()`

Comment: Yep, it solve the issue . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this discussion](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/217), you should use `jsonString()` instead of `json().toString()`.